# where is ubuntu server default download directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am new at ubuntu server. I downloaded a zip file like this.

```
sudo wget http://domain/downloads/1806
```

But I could not find it now. There is a **download** file in **/home/username** folder. But this is not a folder. I can not use **ls** command like this: `ls /home/username/download` it gives a message **Not a directory**.

Comment: Unless instructed otherwise, `wget` downloads the resource to the current directory. So, it depends on where you were when you issued that command.

Comment: btw, you should never need `sudo` to run `wget`. Maybe to save the output file, but for that, better save it somewhere else first and move it later (after inspecting the contents).

Answer (score 9):

When you run:

> sudo wget http://domain.com/downloads/1806

it will download it into the current directory.

You can find your current directory by typing `pwd`

Note that wget sometimes saves the file with a name you might not be expecting - especially if there is a `query string` on the end of the URL - EG `url/?a=1&b=2`

If you run

> ls -lrt

it will list the contents of the current directory, sorted with the newest file at the bottom. So if you run this straight after your download, you'll see the downloaded file as the last one listed.

Hope this helps,

Will